# closures and withUnsafeBufferPointer() in swift

Tags: swift, closures

I'm just trying to get my head around closures in swift.

I want to use the withUnsafeBufferPointer method of an array.  In the simplest form, I can do something like this successfully:

```
var aa:[UInt8] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
var bb = aa.withUnsafeBufferPointer({$0.baseAddress})
```

I can also do this:

```
var bb = aa.withUnsafeBufferPointer({pointerVal in pointerVal.baseAddress})
```

however, I cannot do this without generating an error in xcode:

```
var bb = aa.withUnsafeBufferPointer({pointerVal in return pointerVal.baseAddress})

"Cannot convert the expression's type '((ST5)->(ST5)->ST4)->((ST5)->ST4)->ST4' to type 'R'
```

In the first two assignments, the `return` statement is implied.  If I put it in explicitly, things fail.  I cannot reconcile this with the documentation from Apple. (see chapter on closures in The Swift Programming Language).  I want to put a more complex closure into this, which requires a return statement.  What do I have to do in order to accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the closure contains only a single expression, you need to the specify parameters *and the return type*:

```
var bb = aa.withUnsafeBufferPointer({pointerVal -> UnsafePointer<UInt8> in return pointerVal.baseAddress})
```

or annotate the variable so that the compiler can infer the type:

```
var bb : UnsafePointer<UInt8> = aa.withUnsafeBufferPointer({pointerVal in return pointerVal.baseAddress})
```

But you should use the pointer to the array buffer only inside the closure.
Storing the pointer in a variable like this is unsafe because the array might
be deallocated, the compiler does not know that is is referenced via `bb`.

Comment: I see.  I agree about only using the address inside the closure, that is definitely my intention.